# selenium choose css by two tags

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I was wondering how to locate the text in the following html:

```
<span class='line S_line1' node-type='forward_btn_text'>
  <span>
    <em>text I want</em>
  </span>
</span>
<span class='line S_line1' node-type='comment_btn_text'>
  <span>
    <em>text I DO NOT want</em>
  </span>
</span>
```

Here I only want the text under the node-type "forward_btn_text", how can I distinguish it from that under the "comment_btn_text"?

I am using RSelenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below css.

```
span[node-type='forward_btn_text']
```

[image: dded]

if you want to use both class and node-type attributes then you can use the below.

```
span.line.S_line1[node-type="forward_btn_text"]
```

[image]